# Create a new branch, made a lot of changes, how to view list of files changed?

Tags: mercurial, branch, dvcs, kiln

So there was a new branch created where we made some breaking changes to the codebase.

Now we are going to merge, but before that I want to get a list of all the files that were changed in the branch.

How can I get a list of files? I tried:

```
hg status --change REV
```

But i'm not sure if that is what I want, since I want all files changed in this branch and not a specific revision in the branch.

BTW, how can I view the revision numbers?

Comment: Great, someone has found `hg status --change`! :-) People almost always use `hg diff` or `hg log -v` when they're searching for files changed between two revisions. I'm out of votes right now, but I'll upvote tomorrow!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with

```
$ hg status --rev "branch('your-branch')"
```

to get the changes between the first and the last changeset on the branch (`hg status` will implicitly use `min(branch('your-branch'))` and `max(branch('your-branch'))` when you give it a range of revisions like this).

Since you'll be merging, you should really look at

```
$ hg status --rev default:your-branch
```

to see what is changed *between* the `default` branch and `your-branch`. This shows you the modifications done, and filters out any modifications done on the branch due to merges with `default`.

This is necessary in case your history looks like this:

```
your-branch:      x --- o --- o --- o --- o --- o --- y
                 /           /           /
default:  o --- a --- o --- b --- o --- c --- o --- o --- d
```

where you've already merged `default` into your branch a couple of times. Merging `default` into your branch is normal since you want to regularly integrate the latest stuff from that branch to avoid the branches drifting too far away from each other.

But if a new file was introduced on `default` and later merged up into `B`, then you don't really want to see that in the `hg status` output. You will see it if you do

```
$ hg status --rev a:y
```

since the file was not present in `a`, but is present in `y`. If you do

```
$ hg status --rev d:y
```

then you wont see the file in the output, assuming that it's present in both heads.

---

You write in a comment that you're working *Kiln* repository. They mean "clone" when they say "branch", but the above can still be adapted for your case. All changesets will be on the `default` [named branch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NamedBranches), but that's okay.

Run the following command in your local clone of the "branch" repository:

```
$ hg bookmark -r tip mybranch
```

This marks the current tip as the head of `mybranch`. Then pull all the changesets from the main repository:

```
$ hg pull https://you.kilnhg.com/Repo/public/Group/Main
```

You then mark the *new* tip as the tip of the main repository:

```
$ hg bookmark -r tip main
```

You can now run

```
$ hg status --rev main:mybranch
```

to see the changes between `main` and `my-branch`. If you want to see what you did on the branch itself, the use

```
$ hg status --rev "::mybranch - ::main"
```

The `::mybranch` part will select changesets that are ancestors of `mybranch` — this is all your new work, plus old history from before you branched. We remove the old history with `- ::main`. In older versions of Mercurial, you would use `hg log -r -r mybranch:0 -P main`.

Comment: my branch name is like: `this-is-a-branch`  do I put it in quotes?

Comment: Yes, quotes are mandatory when you have `-` in the branch name.

Comment: how do I know which revision number I branched from?  hg log doesn't have paging, so it flies off my screen buffer!

Comment: strange, hg branch says my branches name is 'default' does this mean it was cloned and not branched?

Comment: Use `hg log -l 30`, `hg log | less`, or the [pager extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PagerExtension) to handle the log. See `hg branches` for the list of all branches. If there's only `default`, then you probably cloned your repo instead of making a [named branch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NamedBranches).

Comment: if it was a branch, would hg parents in the branch folder point to the original trunk?

Comment: yes it seems it was cloned, not branched as I only see default.  But Kiln does show it has a branch, but the command line hg branches just shows default on the trunk repo.

Comment: so I guess that handy command `g status --rev default:your-branch` can't be used now to help filter out what was merged from the other repo.

Comment: Added more help, this time for Kiln.

Comment: sorry little confused, did you outline what SHOULD have been done in order to track changes, or can I do this now?  we didn't tag/bookmark when the clone occurred.

Comment: when I pull in the old "main", do I merge?

Comment: @codecompleting: you can delete old and outdated comments. and yes, the commands I give can be used now in your current situation. You ask if you need to merge — that's really a question you should answer, not me :) You pulled the changesets into your clone so that you can get a list of files changed. If you're happy with the changes, then merge and push back to the main repo.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I prefer to do a test merge from a newly checked-out copy of the repo. This has the advantage that I can see how many conflicts the merge will produce, and I can keep the merge result because I did it in its own copy.

Answer (score 0):

To view the revision numbers, enable the [graphlog extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphlogExtension) and run:

```
$ hg log -b your-branch -G
```

This gives you a nice ASCII graph. This can be handy to quickly look at the graph, but I recommend using [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.org/) for a cross-platform log viewer:

[image: TortoiseHg 2.0 workbench]

Answer (score 0):

I had to merge the default branch into my branch to get some fixes, now the commands above shows also files changed because of merges (this files changed after the merge again in the default branch).

Therefore, to get only the correct files I use something like this:

```
hg log --rev "branch('my-branch') and not merge()" --template '{files}\n' | sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | sort -u
```

if you have spaces in file names, you can do it this way:

```
hg log --rev "branch('my-branch') and not merge()" --template '{rev}\0' | xargs -0 -I @ hg status -n --change @ | sort -u
```

And to answer your last question, revisions can be shown this way:

```
hg log --rev "branch('my-branch') and not merge()" --template '{rev}\n'
```

TIP: I use a hg-alias for this:

```
[alias]
_lf = ! $HG log --rev "branch(\"$1\") and not merge()" --template '{rev}\0' | xargs -0 -I @ hg status -n --change @ | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

With **mercurial**, if you want to **get the list of all the files changed in your current branch** (changes done of your changeset) you can use these commands: :

```
hg log --branch $(hg branch) --stat | grep '|' | awk -F\  '{printf ("%s\n", $1)}' | sort -u
```

Example result:

```
api/tests/test_my_app.py
docker/run.sh
api/my_app.py
```

Explanation of the commands:

```
hg log --branch $(hg branch) --stat
```

Show revision history of entire repository or files and output diffstat-style summary of changes

```
hg branch
```

Show the current branch name

```
grep '|'
```

Search for a text pattern, in this case, it is "|"

```
awk -F\  '{printf ("%s\n", $1)}'
```

Space separator denotes each field in a record and prints each one in a new line

```
sort -u
```

Sort all the printed lines and delete duplicates

Comment: Please add an explanation for what each of these commands do.

Comment: Done! I hope this helps.